# redirection JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i did this code :
**the file index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Jeu de dammes</title>
</head>
<style>
form { margin-left:500px;margin-top:300px;  width:300px }
  </style>
<body>
<form id="formulaire" style="margin-left:100px, padding: 15px" >
<table>
<tr><td><h4> The first player</h4></td>
    <td><input   type="text"   id="premier"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><h4> The second player</h4></td>
    <td><input   type="text"   id="deuxieme"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<button   id="action">Play</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<script   src="jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script>

    $(function () {

        $('#action').click(function () {

            var j1= $('#premier').val();
            var j2= $('#deuxieme').val();

            if( j1=="") alert('saisir le nom du premier joueur');
            if( j2=="") alert('saisir le nom du deuxieme joueur');
            if(j2!="" && j1!="") {$(location).attr('href',"http://www.google.com");}
        });

    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(flower2.jpg)').css('background-size', '100%');
    $("#formulaire").css('background-image', 'url(flower.jpg)');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

my problem is in the event click the redirection to "www.google.com" doesn't work.any suggestions:

1. what is the cause of this error?
2. how can i correct it?

Comment: So, no alert and no redirect? Any logs in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use jQuery to do something that vanilla JavaScript already does:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/";
```

It isn't working probably because you are using a form and that submits before you can redirect. Catch the `submit` event:

Change your code to this and it will work:

```
$('#formulaire').submit(function(e) {
    var j1 = $('#premier').val();
    var j2 = $('#deuxieme').val();

    if (j1 == "") {
        alert('saisir le nom du premier joueur');
    }

    if (j2 == "") {
        alert('saisir le nom du deuxieme joueur');
    }

    if (j2 && j1) {
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: @lamloumi: Redirecting to Google won't work. Google seems to block JS redirects.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Framebuster. JSFiddle displays the website in an `<iframe>`, which most large websites try to break out of.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect, you simply change the `location` global variable:

```
location = "http://www.google.com"
```

What your doing doesn't work because you usually just pass a selector or callback to the jQuery function `$(...)` (e.g. `$("#something a")`.) `location` is a global variable provided by JavaScript.

Comment: jQuery can wrap objects as well.

Comment: i changed "$(location).attr('href',"http://www.google.com");" by "location = "http://www.google.com"" but the same thing!!

Comment: @JanDvorak I guess not, but I'm trying to show he needs an actual URL and not just the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your

```
$(location).attr('href',"http://www.google.com");
```

with a plain Javascript

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com"
```

**Edit:**

Ok, my fault, there was an added problem, you are not returning false when there are problems with the form, nor when you do the redirection, so the deafult action of the form (POST) breaks the previous navigation window.location

Cleaned code a bit and added focus to the fields, when you open the page, and when one of the fields is not filled, just posted a demo at http://fiddle.jshell.net/P3zbb/show/light/

You can see the code mods at http://jsfiddle.net/P3zbb/

Comment: Suggested twice, doesn't solve the problem. The former works as well.

Comment: @JanDvorak you're right ! There was an additional problem, just edited my answer. Try now, please.